# Error while creating processor using lifty

Tags: lift, sbt, processor

I am new to SBT and Lift/Lifty. When I first ran the following command, I had no issues:

> *lift is org.lifty lifty 1.6.1

How come when I run the same command in a different folder, I get the following error:

Label 'lift' already in use: lift is org.lifty lifty 1.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to run the command more than once. It's a global setting for your whole machine. You'll be able to use that processor in any SBT 0.7.x console session.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Where is this setting stored? Is there a command that will undo the setting in case I want to rename it? Just curious.

Comment: It's stored in ~/.ivy/sbt/processors.properties